# can i send a sms using twilio so the sender is my personal number (python)

Tags: python, api, sms, twilio, sms-gateway

I want to send an sms using twilio or any other sms api with python but I want my personal number to show when i send a message. I was also wondering if its possible to do this and text message a short code number?

i tried clockworksms but this did not allow short codes, I just saw twilio does not allow for custom sender to be specified.

Is there any API's that can do this?

clockwork code below:

```
from clockwork import clockwork

api = clockwork.API('apikey')

message = clockwork.SMS(
from_name = "447387967222",
    to = "62555",
    message = 'Opt in')

response = api.send(message)

if response.success:
    print (response.id)
else:
    print (response.error_code)
    print (response.error_message)
```

Comment: You want to send opt-in messages from some random phone number..? Think of the abuse potential and you'll understand why this is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at Twilio [Hosted Numbers](https://www.twilio.com/docs/phone-numbers/hosted-numbers), if your number qualifies. It allows you to host the SMS portion of your phone number on Twilio, and leave the voice portion on your existing carrier. It does not apply to Mobile numbers, however.

As the comment called out, reputable services will not allow spoofing SMS CallerID or for that matter, any other type of CallerID because of the potential for abuse.